# Google map V2 in fragment crash

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I am using navigation drawer so my whole app is in fragments. First time if I open window - everything works. But if i choose from navigation to go to settings and then back - everything crashes or i get empty window. Log shows - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment. I've tried to change android:name to class, but nothing changes. Tried to change MapFragment to SupportFragment. Same thing. I can't change **extends Fragment** to **extends FragmentActivity** because of drawer.

here's my code

```
public class EmployeeMyMove extends Fragment {
      View view; 
      private GoogleMap googleMap;
      MarkerOptions marker, emmarker;
      Location location;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employee_my_move, container, false);
            Log.d("Log", "Tryed");
        } catch (InflateException e) {              
            Log.d("Log", "crashed "+e);
        }
        initilizeMap();


        return view;
   }

   private void initilizeMap() {
    //if (googleMap == null) {
        /*latitudeMine = glob.getLat();
        longitudeMine = glob.getLng();*/

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.MyMoveMap)).getMap();

        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("You are here");
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitudeMine, longitudeMine)).zoom(15).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    //}
}

}
```

And view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/MyMoveMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions on fixing?

Comment: 09-15 15:49:03.421: D/Log(21533): crashed android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin

Comment: Yes. Instant crash. Even first time it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You should override
```

```
public void onDestroy() {
    parentView.removeView(this.mMapView);
    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

```
Take a look at here
```

[Android mapview with fragments can't be added twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818448/android-mapview-with-fragments-cant-be-added-twice)

Comment: Sadly - same ending. Empty layout

Comment: Today i found out that the wrole "crash" problem was entire map fragmen. I destroy it but it can not be created again. Gonna try to create programmatically.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full fix (to all that needs help like this)

**1. To main activity that creates drawer:**

1. Make sure your main activity that creates drawer extends
   FrameActivity
2. Create variable - public static
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
3. Assign it - fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

**2. Your fragment:**

1. Assign googleMap like - googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)
   YourMainActivity.fragmentManager
                       .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
2. **MOST INPORTANT** - override:

@Override

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (googleMap != null) {
        YourMainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .remove(YourMainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
        googleMap = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Gaurav for idea. Helped to find answer. Thank you!